# asp.net mvc 5 XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i have this error on console on every page in the website 
when using firefox is the first image and when using chrome is the seconed image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Tgz.jpg

Comment: On you screenshot only warnings. Please attach screenshot with errors

Comment: Done @VictorLeontyev

Comment: i dont see any problems in console

Comment: did you check the firefox image

Comment: Did you insert FF image?